# Use App Links to open PWA (Progressive Web App) from Facebook

Tags: facebook, applinks, android-app-links

Facebook opens links to my PWA in its own Web View. I would like to use Facebook's "App Links" to open my Progressive Web App.

The meta tags suggested by FB reffer to native apps. For example:

```
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.facebook.samples.sharesample">
```

How do I instruct the FB app to use the installed PWA in the phone to open links that point to it?

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="https://mypwa.com/event/123">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="https://mypwa.com">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="MyPWA.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="Event 123" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Where MyPWA.com is the name I've specified in the manifest.json file: `"name": "MyPWA.com"`

I've also tried putting in the `"short_name": "MyPWA"`  property from my manifest.json

I expected to share PWA links to Facebook and when I click on the shared link, I would have the links open in my progressive web app which is installed on my Android phone.

Comment: `al:android:package` needs to refer to the package name on play store, you can not just put any arbitrary URL in there. I think at most you can specify `al:web:url` and `al:web:should_fallback` here, and hope that this somehow works.